# python read excel XML to DataFrame

Tags: python, xml, excel, dataframe

i'm reading a 20000 x 16 table from [excel XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats#Excel_XML_Spreadsheet_example) file. I'm using this function found on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/hellpanderrr/f5bc0f70ccb637d6fe78#file-python-read-excel-xml-table-md) and it works but really slow. Any way to speed it up?

```
import pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = 'Positions_20171110.xls'

def read_excel_xml(path):
""" Converts Excel XML to a [[[list]]] """
    file = open(path).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(file,'xml')
    workbook = []
    for sheet in soup.findAll('Worksheet'): 
        sheet_as_list = []
        for row in sheet.findAll('Row'):
            row_as_list = []
            for cell in row.findAll('Cell'):
                row_as_list.append(cell.Data.text)
            sheet_as_list.append(row_as_list)
        workbook.append(sheet_as_list)
    return workbook


data = read_excel_xml(source)
df = pd.DataFrame(data[0][1:],columns = data[0][0])
```

Comment: If this works, and you are trying to optimize it, I'd instead post this over at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @BruceWayne  i'll try but looks like a limited site based on tags